# How to update Directive on State Changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angular-directive

I have a root state that defines the overall structure of the Angular template. In the root state, I have the sidebar included that has dynamic menus via directive that changes based on the state. Like this:

```
.state(‘root', {
            abstract: true,
            url: ‘/root',
            templateUrl:  ‘views/root.html',
        })
```

`root.html` includes the `sidebar.html` that has dynamic menu called through Directive like this:

`sidebar.html`

```
  <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
        <li class="nav-header">
                <img alt="avatar" ng-src="{{ avatar }}" />
        </li>

        <!—Dynamic Menus Directive -->
        <li sidebar-menus></li>
    </ul>
```

The directive shows the menu based on `$state.includes()`. But what happens is, the directive shows fine in the first load but it doesn’t update the directive during state changes. To resolve this, I tried the following methods but nothing worked:

1. Added the `$state` to `scope` in Main controller but it still doesn’t change the directive
   once it is compiled first.
2. Tried adding `$stateChangeSuccess` watcher to trigger recompiling the directive, but it doesn’t
   recompile again after the first time (or) maybe it is recompiling but the changes are not seen in the template (this is the code I have now
   which I will give below).
3. Moving the sidebar inside separate child
   states instead of having it in root state works, but it beats the
   purpose since I am trying to load the overall structure in the root
   state first and only refresh the menu sections in subsequent state
   changes.

I am not really sure how to approach this. I have a feeling my approach can be out of whack and hoping someone can guide me here. This is my directive code at the moment:

```
.directive('sidebarMenus', ['$compile', '$state', '$rootScope',
    function($compile, $state, $rootScope) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            var state = scope.$state; // Scope from Main Controller

            // HTML Template
            function contructHtml(state) {

                var htmlText = '';

                // First Child State
                if (state.includes('root.child1')) {
                    var htmlText =  '<li>Child 1 Menu</li>';
                }
                // Second Child State
                if (state.includes('root.child2')) {
                    var htmlText =  '<li>Child 2 Menu</li>';
                }
                // Third Child State
                if (state.includes('root.child3')) {
                    var htmlText =  '<li>Child 3 Menu</li>';
                }

                $compile(htmlText)(scope, function( _element, _scope) {
                            element.replaceWith(_element);
                });

            } 

            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
                    var state = scope.$state; // scope.$state is added in main controller 
                    contructHtml(state);
             });

             // Initial Load 
             contructHtml(state);
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: Why are you compiling the `htmlText`? There are no directives in it.

Comment: Hi @georgeawg what will be ideal in this case please?

Comment: @Neel Use template instead of compiling html, or use a templateUrl.

Comment: Actually I find the solution in the question quite useful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get rid of the compile business by using template.
You template could look something like this:

```
<li ng-if="state.includes('root.child1')">Child 1 Menu</li>
<li ng-if="state.includes('root.child2')">Child 2 Menu</li>
<li ng-if="state.includes('root.child3')">Child 3 Menu</li>
```

So your directive code should look sth like this

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    template:'<div> <li ng-if="state.includes('root.child1')">Child 1 Menu</li>
              <li ng-if="state.includes('root.child2')">Child 2 Menu</li>
              <li ng-if="state.includes('root.child3')">Child 3 Menu</li>     
              </div>'
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        $scope.state = scope.$state; // Scope from Main Controller

        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
            $scope.state = scope.$state; // scope.$state is added in main controller 
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: aha. So it was basically the `compile` that was causing the directive being compiled only once instead of updating during state changes? Thank you Mahendra Singh. I will give your suggestion a try.

Comment: It should probably be `scope.state = scope.$state`. Instead of `var state = scope.$state`.