# Angularjs: How to catch "show event" in custom directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like catch “show event” in my customer directive fired by for example `ng-show`.

How to write such event listener? What’s correct name of the event to listen to?

```
<button ng-click="showMyDirective = !showMyDirective"></button>
<div my-directive="" ng-show="showMyDirective"></div>
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is an example directive with two kinds of listeners of `onclick` event. Both works. Same approach does not work for `show`/`onshow` event.

```
module.directive( 'myDirective' , function() {
    return { function (scope , element , attrs) {

        element.bind('click', function(){
            console.log('element.bind click');
        });

        var div = element[0];
        div.onclick = function(e){
            console.log('div.onclick');
        };

    }; // return
}); // myDirective
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `ng-click` to call a function:

```
<button ng-click="toggleMyDirective()"></button>
```

In your controller, put your "event listener" code into the function:

```
$scope.toggleMyDirective = function() {
    $scope.showMyDirective = !$scope.showMyDirective;
    ... do other stuff here ...
}
```

Edit: Have your directive use a controller and a service:

http://joelhooks.com/blog/2014/02/11/lets-make-full-ass-angularjs-directives/

Comment: This solution depends on code outside of the directive. I am looking for a solution embedded into the directive code.

Comment: How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33807163/how-to-update-directive-on-state-changes

Comment: Thank you for your answer and links. No success so far. It seems to be even more difficult than I thought when I posted the question.